# Powerpoint pasted images are too big

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

When I paste an image on powerpoint, the image is always bigger than Id like.

Oftentimes I will have to paste 20-30 images onto a single slide and arrange them. Resizing every image upon pasting is a huge hassle. If I paste all images first, then resize all, I'll lose track of the order I pasted them. is there a way to modify default pasted image size? Can I make every image rezise to 2" immediately upon pasting?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts, short of writing specific VBA code to solve the problem.

1. Size the images in advance, in an image-editing app that can do batch resizing. IrfanView for Windows does a good job of this and it's free. Usually, if you size the images to 96dpi and 192 pixels wide, they'll come in at 2". What happens exactly may depend on the image format, your Windows DPI settings or whether you're on Windows or Mac.  But it's a starting point.
2. Draw a grid of guides on the Slidemaster | Layout you'll use for these slides and turn on snap to guides. That will make it much simpler to size and position your images.